# Outlook.MailItem.UserProperty disappear after sending mail

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'm trying to add custom UserProperty to MailItem while creating it.

I add an attachement's Hash as UserProperty to my MailItem object.
Then I open my new MailItem in Outlook.

```
mi = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
            Outlook.UserProperties mailUserProperties = null;
            Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = null;

            mi.Attachments.Add(file.FilePath);
            mailUserProperties = mi.UserProperties;
            mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Add("AttachementsHash", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
            mailUserProperty.Value = file.Hash;
            mi.Save();
            mi.Display();
```

If I check MailItem.UserProperties using OutlookSpy BEFORE sending I see that my mail has one UserProperty.

Then I click "Send Mail" in Outlook and I check my mail in SentItems folder.
I can see UserProperties.Count == 0.

If anyone knows why my UserProperty disappear, please help me and tell :)

Comment: What kind of message store are you using? Is the named properties blob gone along with the property that stores the value of the property (click IMessage in OutlookSpy)?

Answer (score 4):

With a lot of effort i resolved my problem.

UserProperties are removed after sending mail. But in stead of UserProperties I used MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty

[MSDN Documentation of Property Accessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863046.aspx)

```
        string prop = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PropertyName";
        mi.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(prop, propertyValue.ToString());
```

And then on event 'ItemAdd' I checked, if item was added to sentItems.
If it Was added to sentItems I read properties using such construction:

```
Outlook.MailItem AddedMail = item as Outlook.MailItem;
                    string attachmentProperty = AddedMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E");
```

And then finnally I parse string in order to get my data.

I hope it will help anyone :)

Comment: I copied your code but still on the "Reply" event of the email where the PropertAccessor should be set then I get I only null from the GetProperty. Can I use the same code like you did, same GUIDs or are they must be generated dynamically? or maybe the cause is that I GetProperty from the "reply email" and not the original one?