# Outlook, best way to store variable in an appointment

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, rtf

Working on an Outlook Add-In, I need to store a variable inside an appointment to ensure that the recipients can read it.
 So far, I used UserProperty and RTF bookmarks. Both are fine until the invitation crosses the border of the organisation (leave my exchange domain). When it happens, userproperties and RTF bookmarks seem to be removed. Has anyone find a reliable way to do this? I want to avoid ugly hack such as including the variable in small fonts inside the body.

- Option 1: Maintain user property => Not possible
- Option 2: Maintain clean RTF

The RTF seems to be converted in a HTML compatible RTF and some tags are lost. The one that I am particulary interested is the following:

Original RTF:

```
{\\field{\\*\\fldinst{\\ltrch\\f1\\fs22\\cf1\\ulnone\\ulc1 HYPERLINK 
{\\plain\\ltrch\\f0\\fs24\\ltrch\\f1\\fs22\\cf1\\ulnone\\ulc1 https://www.google.com \\\\o MYLINKNAME}}
```

Converted RTF:

```
{\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \"https://www.google.com\"}}
```

The link title property is removed which prevents to retrieve it on the recipient side.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by **crossing the border** but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423979/outlook-mailitem-userproperty-disappear-after-sending-mail?rq=1) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I clarified the point. Your reference is a good one but unfortunately not applicable as the calendar/mail item is still on the sender inbox. I need to evaluate options allowing me to store data and retrieve them on the recipients side.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much you can do once your appointments get converted to the iCal format when it is being sent over SMTP to a user outside your Exchange org.

But you can force Outlook send the meeting updates in the RTF format - set `UseTnef` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B`) to true using `MeetingItem.PropertyAccwessor.SetProperty` in the `Application.ItemSend` event. Note that the property must be set on the outgoing `MeetingItem` object, and  `Application.ItemSend` event is the only time you have access to it before it gets sent.

Comment: Forgot about UseTnef  property -see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry for your expertise on this. I tried void Item_Send(ref bool Cancel){ string property = "schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B";Boolean value = true; this.Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(property, value);} but do not see any difference in the generated RTF format. I edited the question to clarify the issue related to the RTF.

Comment: Did you verify that the property is correctly set on the meeting item in the Sent Items folder? You can do that with OutlookSpy - select the item, click IMessage button.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, sorry for the delayed answer, I was making additional tests. Yes I do believe that the attribut is correctly set. Unfortunately I cannot use OutlookSpy on the test machine but have verified the values of the sent item, see the picture here: https://imgur.com/a/9ufivGw the first value is generated using the ID 8582000B and the second using string Usetnef. The recipient still receives the same HTML RTF.

Comment: So what do you see when the meeting request is received?

Comment: I see a modified RTF which is a mix of HTML and RTF generated by Outlook. The output is still a valid RTF document which is well displayed by Outlook but it is far far from the original one. If you look to the edited initial post, I put an example of the original vs converted format.

Comment: I meant what do you see on the MAPI level (click IMessage button in OutlookSpy). Is your property set on the incoming meeting request?

Comment: Well it seems that the property is not present: https://imgur.com/a/PVfE998

Comment: What is the value of the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property?